# XSLT3 Streaming for appending integer position of node

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a large XML file to transform using XSLT to append the integer position of sibling node . I’m using XSLT3 streaming and accumulators. I did get desired output. However, my code looks so lengthy that I’m unable to simplify my code. I also need to group same sibling nodes as sibling nodes in the source xml is not grouped always. Could someone help me here please?

Requirement: Sibling nodes such as Positions, Payments etc.. need to be appended with their corresponding integer position such as `<Locations1>`, `<Locations2>`etc.`<Payments1>`,`< Payments2>` etc..

Now that I have declared two accumulators, each for each sibling nodes. However, my source XML has many sibling nodes.. I’m not sure if I need to use as many accumulators and template match as my sibling nodes.

Input XML

``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Members>
    <Member>
        <Name>
            <fname>Fred</fname>
            <id>1234</id>
        </Name>
        <Locations>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations>
        <Locations>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations>
        <Payments>
            <amount>1000</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments>
        <Payments>
            <amount>1000</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments>
        <Locations>
            <name>New York</name>
            <days>5</days>
            <hours>40</hours>
        </Locations>
        <Locations>
            <name>Boston</name>
            <days>4</days>
            <hours>32</hours>
        </Locations>
    </Member>
    <Member>
        <Name>
            <fname>Jack</fname>
            <id>4567</id>
        </Name>
        <Locations>
            <name>New York</name>
            <days>5</days>
            <hours>30</hours>
        </Locations>
        <Locations>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations>
        <Payments>
            <amount>1500</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments>
        <Payments>
            <amount>1800</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments>
    </Member>
</Members>
```

``

Expected Output

``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Members>
    <Member>
        <Name>
            <fname>Fred</fname>
            <id>1234</id>
        </Name>
        <Locations_1>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations_1>
        <Locations_2>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations_2>
        <Locations_3>
            <name>New York</name>
            <days>5</days>
            <hours>40</hours>
        </Locations_3>
        <Locations_4>
            <name>Boston</name>
            <days>4</days>
            <hours>32</hours>
        </Locations_4>
        <Payments_1>
            <amount>1000</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_1>
        <Payments_2>
            <amount>1000</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_2>     
            </Member>
    <Member>
        <Name>
            <fname>Jack</fname>
            <id>4567</id>
        </Name>
        <Locations_1>
            <name>New York</name>
            <days>5</days>
            <hours>30</hours>
        </Locations_1>
        <Locations_2>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations_2>
        <Payments_1>
            <amount>1500</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_1>
        <Payments_2>
            <amount>1800</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_2>
    </Member>
</Members>
```

``

Current code
``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="loc-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member/Locations" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="pay-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member/Payments" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="Locations">
        <xsl:element name="Locations_{accumulator-before('loc-count')}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Payments">
        <xsl:element name="Payments_{accumulator-before('pay-count')}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

``

Current Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Members>
    <Member>
        <Name>
            <fname>Fred</fname>
            <id>1234</id>
        </Name>
        <Locations_1>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations_1>
        <Locations_2>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations_2>
        <Payments_1>
            <amount>1000</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_1>
        <Payments_2>
            <amount>1000</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_2>
        <Locations_3>
            <name>New York</name>
            <days>5</days>
            <hours>40</hours>
        </Locations_3>
        <Locations_4>
            <name>Boston</name>
            <days>4</days>
            <hours>32</hours>
        </Locations_4>
    </Member>
    <Member>
        <Name>
            <fname>Jack</fname>
            <id>4567</id>
        </Name>
        <Locations_1>
            <name>New York</name>
            <days>5</days>
            <hours>30</hours>
        </Locations_1>
        <Locations_2>
            <name>Chicago</name>
            <days>3</days>
            <hours>24</hours>
        </Locations_2>
        <Payments_1>
            <amount>1500</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_1>
        <Payments_2>
            <amount>1800</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </Payments_2>
    </Member>
</Members>
```

Comment: What is that new requirement to group elements about? Can you edit the samples of input and wanted output where that is necessary, to illustrate the grouping task? And as pure streaming is often difficult to achieve, what is the exact structure of the input XML that requires the use of streaming, are there thousands or more, but separate `Member` elements, where each `Member` holds only a relatively small number of child elements?

Comment: Hi @Martin Honen Thanks for checking this. I just edited my question. The reason why we need streaming is, input XML is a large input file from a accounting journal system and we expect huge volume of data could cause performance issues with many `Member` elements contain many `Child` elements

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, my sympathy. XML that uses names like Payments_1 and Payments_2 is really bad news, someone is going to hate you for generating it like this. But if that's the kind of XML you've been told to produce, I guess it's not your job to question it.

As far as the requirements are concerned, you haven't made it clear whether the various kinds of sibling nodes are always grouped as in your example (all Locations, then all Payments, etc), or whether they can be interleaved.

One way you might be able to reduce the volume of code is by having a single accumulator holding a map. The map would use element names as the key and the current sibling count for that element as the value.

```
<accumulator name="counters" as="map(xs:QName, xs:integer)" initial-value="map{}">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member" select="map{}"/>
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member/*" select="map:put($value, node-name(.), if (map:contains($value, node-name(.)) then map:get($value, node-name(.))+1 else 1"/>
</accumulator>

<xsl:template match="Members/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}_{accumulator-before('counters')(node-name(.))}">
    ....
```

Another way to do the conditional map:put is

```
map:put($value, node-name(.), ($value(node-name(.)), 0)[1] + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your inputs. Yes, I have been asked to provide the XML with integer position of node names.

Comment: I get error "Cannot find a 1-argument function named {http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map}contains(). The namespace URI and local name are recognized, but the number of arguments is wrong"  when I add code <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member/*" select="map:put($value, node-name(.), if (map:contains(node-name(.)) then map:get(node-name(.))+1 else 1"/>  Seems like <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member/*" select="map:put($value, node-name(.), ($value(node-name(.)), 0)[1] + 1)"/> is returning exact source input xml as output. could you please a take a look and help?

Comment: I also have to group the sibling nodes. I have edited my original question. Not sure how do i use for-each group with accumulators.

Comment: Corrected the simple coding errors. The grouping requirement makes it a completely different question; please don't edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers, it makes the site very confusing for subsequent readers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group the `Member` child elements by `node-name()` then I think you need to wrap the `xsl:for-each-group` into `xsl:fork`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="counters"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="counters" as="map(xs:QName, xs:integer)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member" select="map{}"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Member/*" 
            select="map:put($value, node-name(), if (map:contains($value, node-name())) then map:get($value, node-name()) + 1 else 1)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="Member">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:fork>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:fork>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member/*">
        <xsl:element name="{node-name()}_{accumulator-before('counters')(node-name())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This approach only shows the grouping, it doesn't try to special case `Name` elements or some other way to not output an index if there is only one such element.